# How does Kotlin's "as" cast operator affect branch coverage?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, code-coverage

How can I achieve branch coverage for an expression in which the "as" casting has been used, in this code
for the expression `errorCode = result.data as Int`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This bug fix in the Jacoco (version0.8.8 [Changelog](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html)) coverage tool offers an explanation:

> Branch added by the Kotlin compiler version 1.6.0 and above for "unsafe" cast operator is filtered out during generation of report (GitHub [1266](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/1266))

Thus, the Kotlin compiler may generate a hidden branch for the cast (checking whether the cast is possible at all) which then surfaces in the coverage tool used.

From a functional perspective, you may want to add a test case that covers the situation that `result.data` doesn’t contain an int. That would probably lead to full coverage of the cast statement as well.

Though I am not a Kotlin developer, the unsafe cast raises the following questions:

1. The `null != errorCode` check suggests that `errorCode` is of type `Int?` and not of type `Int` which can never be null.
2. This also suggests the type cast can be safe, via `result.data as? Int`, where the `as?` operator returns null on failure.
3. Interestingly the coverage of your `null != errorCode` if-condition suggests that both the true and false branch are covered. I doubt this is the case. Instead, the compiler may have concluded that the condition can never be false (since `errorCode` has the non nullable type `Int`), and therefore optimized the else branch away.

In other words, switching to `Int?` and `as?` will likely move the reported uncovered branch to your `null != errorCode` if-condition, where it makes more sense.